# Oracle 12c UTL_HTTP Cookie Value Length greater than 1024

Tags: oracle, cookies, oracle12c

UTL_HTTP has a limit for the value of a cookie of 1024 characters - however I have cookies that exceed that length with a value of around 1700 characters. Is there any way I can submit an HTTP request via UTL_HTTP using cookies with a value greater than 1024 characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to figure this out, at least enough to get it working in my case. Instead of using the UTL_HTTP.ADD_COOKIES / UTL_HTTP.GET_COOKIES procedures I'm reading/setting the HTTP headers manually. Looping through the response headers and parsing out the contents of the "Set-Cookie" header and then passing that in to the next request using the "Cookie" header via UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER. Not very elegant, but it's working.